# Python 2.7.1 import MySQLdb working via cmd but no in a .py file

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, mysql-python

Okay, i have Python2.7.1 installed in a windows 32.

The problem is, when i try to import MySQLdb module via python in cmd,

python recognizes the module well,

but when i try the same script in a python file i got: ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

Anyone have faced same issue ?

Just to make more clear.
Via cmd:

C:\Users\Desktop>python
Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:32:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import MySQLdb

via .py file
C:\Users\Desktop>TesteDB12.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fs0222\Desktop\TesteDB12.py", line 1, in 
    import MySQLdb
ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

By the way i had python 3.5 before on my machine but i already changed my enviroment variables to fit python 2.7, i flush the cache, restarted my machine, tryed python mysqldb installers .exe .msi, and still the same problem.

By the way couple months ago i was able to use this module normally.

Any helps ? Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the source path of python(.exe) in the first line of your python code

May be as follows:

```
#!C:\Python26\python.exe

import MySQLdb
```